# Removal of specific string and anything after

Tags: r, stringr, strsplit

I would like to remove 'sat' and anything after but not 'saturday'. Although this seems quite simple I have been unable to find a thread on this.

Example:

```
text <- c("good morning amer sat","this morning saturday")
```

Desired Result:

```
"good morning amer","this morning saturday"
```

Everything I do removes saturday.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use word boundary (`\\b`)

```
sub("\\s*\\bsat\\b", "", text)
```

-output

```
[1] "good morning amer"     "this morning saturday"
```

---

Or with `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
str_remove(text, "\\s*\\bsat\\b")
[1] "good morning amer"     "this morning saturday"
```

Answer (score 3):

Here with `str_replace`:

```
library(stringr)

str_replace(text, ' sat$', '')

[1] "good morning amer"    
[2] "this morning saturday"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution, using negative lookaround and `stringr::str_remove` (although, I am not sure whether you want to remove `sat` *only* or remove `sat` and *every* following character):

```r
library(stringr)

str_remove(text, "\\s*sat(?!urday).*$")

#> [1] "good morning amer"     "this morning saturday"
```